# What is the good strategy to backup mongodb's data without locking it (fsync & lock)?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-ec2, backup, amazon-ebs, database

We have a mongodb running on only one AWS EC2 (no master-slave, no replica sets). The data files are stored in a separate EBS volume. So, what is the best way to backup and restore the data without locking it from writing (sync & lock)? Or we must have master-slave to achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have journaling enabled (the default in MongoDB 2.0+), you can take advantage of **EBS snapshots** to get a consistent dump of the data files without the need for `fSyncLock()`.

This is covered in more detail in the  [EC2 Backup & Restore](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/) documentation on the MongoDB site.

Comment: Thank you. By the way, I still have some concerns on db performance when performing the ebs snapshot. Does it affect the performance much? And if yes, is there any better solution?

Comment: In my experience the EBS performance in general has been inconsistent, but EBS Snapshots are the point-in-time backup strategy supported by Amazon Web Services. Actual impact will vary based on your system utilization, file system, size of the data dir, frequency of snapshots, and the weather patterns of EBS :).

Comment: As for alternatives, there is a good overview in [MongoDB Backup and Restoration Strategies](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/).  It is worth considering using a replica set as you will have a hot standby with a full data backup and there are other administrative benefits versus a single server.  For example, you can do your backups from a secondary without affecting the primary server.  You could also have nodes in other availability zones for failover.  A replica set isn't a replacement for an archival backup strategy, but can be a good complement.

Answer (score 0):

At MongoDirector.com we use LVM snapshotos to backup our MongoDB databases. As your DB size gets larger it really is the only option. If you use MongoDump and try to restore using MongoRestore it might take hours. In 2.0+ the `fsyncLock()` is optional but we do it anyways.